# Unexpected token ) while deplying node application on azure?

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service

I am facing following issue while deploying node application on azure windows.

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
at Module._compile (module.js:434:25)
at Object..js (module.js:464:10)
at Module.load (module.js:353:31)
at Function._load (module.js:311:12)
at Module.require (module.js:359:17)
at require (module.js:375:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (D:\home\site\wwwroot\bin\www.js:6:11)
at Module._compile (module.js:446:26)
at Object..js (module.js:464:10)
at Module.load (module.js:353:31)
```

Application has thrown an uncaught exception and is terminated:

contents of www.js at line 6

`var app = require('../app');`

the application works fine if i run it locally with npm start or on azure linux.

**Can anyone help?**

Comment: Please provide the www.js else will not be able to debug it.

Comment: i was able to resolve it by updating WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION to 10.15.2, by default azure uses node  0.6 which was not working for me.

Comment: Please add this comment and add it in the answer and accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to resolve it by updating `WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION` to `10.15.2`, by default azure uses `node 0.6` which was not working for me.